# send messages from aurora mysql to sqs

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have two `lambdas` and an `SQS` queue in between. The first lambda's purpose is to pick product ids from `aurora MySQL` and send to `SQS`. There is over 7 million product ids. When the first lambda sends these product ids to SQS, I have enabled a trigger which invokes my second lambda.

The issue I am facing is that my first lambda is not able to send all product ids to queue in 1 invocation due to the time limits of lambda. I tested it and for 1 invocation it was able to send only 100k records to SQS. If I run it again obviously it will again pick the same product ids. Even if I put a limit and offset in my lambda then after 1st invocation I'll have to change offset to pick the next 100k records, this is a bit tedious. How can I automate this process?

Comment: Hi Nats, why the second lambda read from my-sql directly?
The time threshold on lambda is 15 minutes by default, i would say you can write for sure more than 100K records in 15minutes. Did you check the performance of your query which outputs the records? if you have code within your lambda which runs and outputs the record i suggest move that to mysql stored procedure (SP) and execute from lambda by calling the SP. 
If all above fails you can try to execute SP in Lambda-1 and output it to a txt file which can be used as an input in the second Lambda, instead of queue.

Comment: if queue is must in your architecture you may want to try provisioned lambda option where you can save couple of minutes to make sure lambda does not require any warm up time. But it may not solve the big picture, may be worth a try though

Comment: @AModgil The second lambda doesn't read directly from mysql, it reads from the queue. It is the first lambda which picks product ids from database. I have over 7 million product ids.

Comment: Sorry I meant why not second lambda take the feed directly from my sql? Why is the queue required in the middle. Typo in above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried writing to s3 a csv file that stores the latest index/productid you have sent to SQS, which you will eventually access at the start of the next iteration of your lambda?

Here's a rough implementation of the steps:

1. Load latest index/productid from s3
2. [Any other processes that you do]
3. Rewrite csv file on s3 that stores latest index/productid

Comment: I have to rewrite csv to the same bucket right?